# Eclipse Plug-In developement, long running task

Tags: eclipse, plugins, asynchronous, code-injection

I have several UI-Components which have listeners. All these listeners invoke method `dialogChanged()`. My goal is to make some long processing in this method and don't let the UI freeze. According to [Lars Vogel](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseJobs/article.html#eclipsejobs_jobs) it is possible to do this with help of `UISynchronize` being injected during runtime. But it fails for me, field of this type is not being injected and i get a `NullPointerException`. Here's relevant part of my code:

```
@Inject UISynchronize sync;
Job job = new Job("My Job") {

    @Override
    protected IStatus run(IProgressMonitor arg0)
    {
        sync.asyncExec(new Runnable()
        {
            @Override
            public void run()
            {
                updateStatus("Checking connection...");
                if (bisInstallDirSelected)
                    bisSettingsChanged();
                else
                    jarSettingsChanged();
            }
        });
        return Status.OK_STATUS;
    }

};
protected void dialogChanged()
{
    job.schedule();
}
```

The methods `updateStatus(String s)`, `bisSettingsChanged()` and `jarSettingsChanged()` interact with UI, to be presice, they use method `setErrorMessage(String newMessage)` of superclass `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage`
I'd appreciate if somebody could tell me what I am doing wrong or suggest a better way to handle this problem.

Comment: What is the class containing this code? @Inject only works in classes that the application model knows about (such as the class for an MPart).

Comment: The class indirectly extends `org.eclipse.jface.wizard.WizardPage` and has no other dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only use @Inject in classes that the e4 application model creates (such as the class for a Part or a Command Handler).

You can also use `ContextInjectionFactory` to do injection on your own classes.

For classes where injection has not been done you can use the 'traditional' way of running code in the UI thread:

```java
Display.getDefault().asyncExec(runnable);
```

Comment: I already tried to work with `getShell().getDisplay().asyncExec()` but the UI freezes during execution of `dialogChanged()`. Same applies for your suggestion with static method.

Comment: I also used `Thread.currentMethod()` to compare the thread which runs the runnable to the thread which invokes `dialogChanged()` and it turned out to be the same thread (`main`). It explaines why the UI freezes but I expected `asyncExec()' to swap processing into external thread.

Comment: Wait... I think I understand my error :) I need somehow to separate code which blocks processing from code which interacts with UI...